# How do I curve procedurally generated textures (Clouds)?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I'm quite new to blender and am still getting the hang of things. Having followed [BlenderMaster's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJd5WS6e9Cg) on creating clouds, I've managed to create something like this:
[image]
[image]

I already know how to move the clouds in XY axis and to control the density, but how do I bend/revolve/twist/curve the clouds into a specific direction using the node editor? Something like this:
[image]

All help is much appreciated.